# Getting the model class from active record relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Rails model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

Given an active record relation:

```
limited_foo = Foo.where(...)
```

how can I get the original model class?

```
limited_foo ... # => Foo
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Relation` has an *attribute_reader* `klass`:

```
limited_foo.klass
#=> Foo
```

Source is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L21). Alias `model` works as well.